# How to use third column as identifier in line-graph

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, diagrams

I want to draw a diagram(line-graph) from a three column sheet

### Input

```
| Date          | Value         | Identifier |
| ------------- | ------------- | ---------- |
| 01-04-2014    | 1             | John       |
| 01-04-2014    | 2             | Maja       |
| 01-04-2014    | 27            | Jim        |
| 02-04-2014    | 32            | John       |
| 02-04-2014    | 12            | Maja       |
| 02-04-2014    | 5             | Jim        |
| 02-04-2014    | 79            | Bob        | # Identifiers can (dis)appear on new dates
| ...           |               |            |
```

### Expected output:

One (independent) line per identifier. Value on Y-axis, Date on X-axis.

**How do I set this up in LibreOffice - Calc?**

I **don't** want to use the identifier as a column header - means: I don't want to have colum headers for **John, Maja, Jim, ...**

### Example output

[image: http://www.ooowiki.de/DiagrammMitLinien.html]
<sub>X=Date,Y=Value, Lines per *Identifier* - of course there should be only *one* line per identifier</sub>

Comment: @Raystafarian updated the answer, hope this is more clear now :)

Comment: i'm almost sure tthat the only solution is to transform your data so the "identifiers" get column names. You could do this automatically using a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data > Pivot Table.
Mark the source data and generate a Pivot Table with

- Date in 'Row fields'
- Identifier in 'Column fields', and
- Value in 'Data fields'.

The Pivot Table converts the linear table into a cross table. Then mark the data from the Pivot Table and generate your chart